# Nginx CORS with multiple origins works with GET and not with POST methods

Tags: nginx, cors

I have this problem. My boss wanted me to make our Nginx proxy to work with more than one origin.
So far so good. I did the following:

in `cors.conf` file:

```
if ($http_origin ~ 'HERE COMES THE REGEX FOR THE ORIGINS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,username,x-auth-token' always;
}
```

Then in `nginx.conf` I do this:

```
server {
    etc...
    etc...
    location /api/api1/ {
            proxy_pass http://api1/;
            include     cors.conf;
        }
   etc...
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
It works with all GET requests from both origins, but fails with anything else.
I couldn't find solution so far, but I need one.
Any help or idea is appreciated.
Thank you

P.S. I tried with map instead of using if, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution myself based on: https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487?permalink_comment_id=2752219#gistcomment-2752219

in my `cors.conf` file I changed the content to this:

```
set $origin '$http_origin';

if ($origin !~ 'HERE COMES THE REGEX FOR THE ORIGINS') {
    set $origin 'Here comes the url of one of the allowed origins';
}

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$origin' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,username,x-auth-token' always;
```